# How can I rename CSV fields in the Altova MapForce GUI?

Tags: xml, csv

In [Altova MapForce](http://www.altova.com/mapforce.html) I can map XML to CSV but when I append fields through the CSV Component Settings dialog it always gives a default name to the field (e.g. Field12).

I can change these default field names by changing the .mfd mapping definition file in a text editor but I'm sure there must be a way to do this through the GUI. Is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply click the column name (in the component settings dialog) to edit. You might have to switch off "First row contains field names" first.

Comment: Yes, it's the 'First row contains field names' checkbox that was preventing this. Thanks!